# Can't run compiled java file with main method

Tags: java, maven

I have an application, which I try to build using Maven. I can build a jar, but running it does nothing: it can't find a Main class. I set however the MainClass in the POM. When I try to run the MainPane.class in the target folder from the command line returns: 
"Error: could not find or load Main class MainPane". (After navigating inside the target folder and run 'java MainPane')

I can run this class from Eclipse and it has a main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("test");
}
```

I should be able to run the class file in the target folder right? What can possibly go wrong?

Comment: Is the class File `MainPane.class' in this folder? Try `java -cp ./ MainPane'

Comment: *"I should be able to run the class file in the target folder right?"* Provided `MainPane` isn't in a package, yes, if the current directory is in the classpath (I believe it is by default, but you could try `java -cp . MainPane`).

Comment: @Jens: What's the `/` on that for?

Comment: @Jens, the MainPane is in this folder (when I type dir I see the MainPane.class), however this command results the same error

Comment: @TJ the MainPane is in a package, should I prefix the class with nl.tudelft.blabla?

Comment: where is your pom file? Do mvn clean install from same path as your pom file.

Comment: @Lodewijck Go to your the folder in wich is your package and try `java -cp ./ nl.tudelft.blabla.MainPane`

Comment: @Jens: I have a target folder with the Maven build (Client-1.0.jar) in it, and the folders of the package name classes/nl/tudelft.... Should I run this command from the target folder?

Comment: @Sanjaya I made the Maven structure using Eclipse, the pom is next to the target and the src folder. I did Maven clean install, from eclipse, still the same error message.

Comment: @Lodewijck try it from the classes folder. if you want to try it fromm the target folder ou have to run command java -cp ./Client-1.0.jar MainPane

Comment: @Jens Aah java -cp ./Client-1.0.jar nl.tudelft....MainPane works! But the jar still gives the error, how do we fix this?

Comment: @Lodewijck Is the jar- File containing the class (with package)?

Comment: @Jens Yep the file is in the jar. But I get classNotFound exceptions. Should I add a classpath in the pom?

Comment: @Lodewijck can you give me the command line you use.

Comment: Now: 'java -jar client-5.0.jar', which says: 'no main manifest attribute in client-5.0.jar'

Comment: @Lodewijck try 'java -cp ./client-5.0.jar nl.tudelft.blabla.MainPane'

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell java where the class is by defining the -classpath parameter

```
java -classpath classes MainPane
```

Or from the project directory

```
java -classpath target/classes MainPane
```

Also make sure you are using the full package name if you have one

```
java -classpath target/classes my.package.name.MainPane
```

@AndyGeeDe

TomEE treibt Tomitribe! | http://tomee.apache.org

Comment: It returns the same error, isn't this the same as navigating inside the target folder and call the MainPane from its directory?

Comment: Then search for the MainPane.class in your target directory and let us know where you find it?

Comment: If it is directly in the target folder then this is not a standard maven location. Try: java -classpath . MainPane

Comment: The MainPane.class in in target/classes/nl/tudelft/.../MainPane.class, the created jar file is also in the target folder

Answer (score 1):

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

Will only work if the jar's manifest contains the "Main-Class: classname" entry. Check for that. If it is not present then you can still run you application via this command:

```
java -cp ./my.jar package/class_name
```

Comment: Yep, this works, however it throws classNotFoundExceptions and it should not. The main-class is set in the manifest of the jar.

Comment: Can you post a layout of the created jar and the contents of the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Try googling on "maven executable jar". Once you get the build correct, you can run it using

java -jar myjar.jar

Java is not terribly good at this. The executable jar needs all the dependent jars unpacked, and a manifest file included that names the main class. To my mind is less than elegant but it does work.